# Performance.now() execution time on different platforms

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, performance-testing

I'm testing the time performance of an location based encryption library I wrote in Typescript using webcryptoapi. I wanted to see time differences for different platforms such as MacOs, and android. To do so, I use my Macbook pro(2017) and Samsung galaxy s2 android tablet.

To test the library, I created a simple HTML page with some text box area , encryption button and decryption button. When button is clicked, encryption takes place. Now below as can be seen from the **performance.now()** function I calculate the time difference and log it onto console. However, I realized that encryption time is always smaller on tablet compare to macbook pro computer. Logically, aren't  laptops stronger than the tablets ? Or does it have to do with API calls speed?  I don't get the reason why tablet is always faster even though it a less powerful device. Thanks in advance.

```
public async encrypt(transformedLocation: Int32Array, message: String, toleranceDistance: number) {
    let context = this
    try {
        let keyDerivationStartTime = performance.now();
        let key = await this.deriveKey(transformedLocation)
        let keyDerivationFinishTime = performance.now();
        let keyhash = await this.calculateKeyHash(key)
        let plaintTextBytes = DataConvertionCalculations.stringToByteArray(message)
        let encryptionStartTime = performance.now();
        let encryptedMessage = await this.encryptMessage(key, plaintTextBytes)
        let encryptionFinishTime = performance.now();
        let result = new ResultHolder(encryptedMessage, keyhash, toleranceDistance, context.salt, context.ivBytes)
        let wholeTime= performance.now();
        console.log("Key derivation time:" + (keyDerivationFinishTime-keyDerivationStartTime))
        console.log("Encryption operation time:" + (encryptionFinishTime-encryptionStartTime))
        console.log("Whole encryption operation took:" + (wholeTime-keyDerivationStartTime))
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use Safari on both the tablet and the desktop? Note that some JavaScript engines have [hampered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) `performance.now()` to mitigate Spectre and the like. Firefox's SpiderMonkey still does I believe; Chrome's V8 doesn't on some OS's and does on others depending on whether they can use their other Spectre mitigation on the OS. I don't know what Apple's JavaScriptCore does. (Side note: On iOS, currently all browsers have to use JavaScriptCore, not the engine they usually use, due to Apple limitations on apps.)

Comment: I have used chrome browser for testing purposes both on tablet and the macbook pro. tablet is somewhat always faster. Then I opened firefox on the mac and still kept using chrome on the tablet. Tablet beats everytime. I mean its alright that its faster but I need to reason this for a master thesis. Thats where I am getting stucked at  as I dont understand the reason.

Comment: Just be aware that although you're using Chrome on the tablet, if it's an iOS device, you're not using Google's V8, you're using Apple's JavaScriptCore. (`performance.now` is a host-provided function, so may differ between iOS Chrome and iOS Safari, but...)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but like I said before in the initial post, tablet is an android tablet( samsung galaxy tab s2)

Comment: Doh. I didn't read carefully and assumed you were using an iOS tablet if you were comparing it to a Mac OS desktop.